# Equivalent to RotationAngle in order to rotate a label in a TMS Web Core Website?

Tags: delphi, rotation, rotatetransform, tms, tms-web-core

In FireMonkey, there's a `RotationAngle` property on most of the visual components. You can use that on a `TLabel` to rotate it to have the text face different directions such as:

[image: Delphi RotationAngle]

How can this be achieved in TMS WEB Core? I don't see any `RotationAngle` or `Rotate` or any such properties that could be used for rotating a label.